# Creating a POJO class Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm new to Retrofit please help me.

I have a JSON file with different arrays and objects.

When I use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to create classes it generates different classes like

```
-----------------------------------com.example.Properties.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Properties {
...
...
...
}

-----------------------------------com.example.Metadata.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

 public class Metadata {
 ...
 ...
 ...
 }
```

So my question is, if I need only 1 class objects, do I need to define all the classes in project?

Comment: If you don't want any class then no need to keep it. You can remove it but make sure that that class doesn't have reference in any remaining POJO classes.

Comment: @Usman [Json] (http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2014-01-01&endtime=2014-01-02&limit=2)  i want only the properties value

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is if the class represent some json key in your json. Or you can leave the mapping class for that json key. In this case that json key will not be deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

Many classes generating in jsonschema2pojo means

> You have many `jsonarrays` in `jsonarray`

You must need it for extracting data.